# .Net8 publish for linux-arm32 in VisualStudio

Tags: .net, linux, arm, publish

I am using VidualStudio 2022 on Windows 11 and have a small .net8 application I want to publish for linux-arm32, calles Project_A.
This ptoject relies on another project in my solution, lets call it Project_B.
The targetplatform for Project_B is Any, because it is used in an Windows application too.

If I build this solution, no errors appear.

For publishing Project_A I choose these options:

- .Net8
- standalone
- linux-arm
- single file

Publishing stops at the moment the system tries to findt the .dll of project_B.
The path whre it should be is: ..Project_B\obj\Release\net8.0\linux-arm\ref\Project_B.dll
but in the directory ..Project_B\obj\Release\net8.0 there is no folder named "linux-arm"

I am new to linux and publishing for this OS.
What are I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Project_B was a consoleapplication and not a classlibrary.
After Change it to classlibrary, everything works as expected.